# MVC Dynamic List binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, kendo-grid, model-binding

I have a List Property in a model

```
public class MyModel
{
   public MyModel()
    {
        ChildModels = new List<ChildModels>();
    }
  // other properties
  public List<ChildModel> ChildModels {get; set;}
}

public class ChildModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Name {get;set;}
    public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

In the form submit the html markup that generates is like this

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="ChildModels_0__Id" name="ChildModels[0].Id" type="hidden" value="0">
    <input id="ChildModels_0__Name" name="ChildModels[0].Name" type="hidden" value="value 1">
    <div class="control-label col-md-3">
        <label for="Value">value 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="control-text col-md-7">
        <input class="form-control" id="ChildModels_0__Value" name="ChildModels[0].Value" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

When the form is posted back the `ChildModels` is being `null`. Other properties have values. I cannot even see `ChildModels` in the Request headers of Network tab in Google Chrome.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

This problem was due to Kendo Grid. It does not parse the child objects when editing a record in an editor template. 
To solve this issue I had to write a javascript function that parses child objects.. like this

```html
function serialize(data) {
    serializeArray("ChildModels", data["ChildModels"], data);
}

function serializeArray(prefix, array, result) {
    var listattrs = $(".ValueAttributesClass"); // Add this class to one of the property of your child model 
    for (var i = 0; i < listattrs.length; i++) {
        result[prefix + "[" + i + "].Id"] = $("#" + listattrs[i].id).val();
        result[prefix + "[" + i + "].Name"] = $("#" + listattrs[i].id.replace("Id", "Name")).val();
        result[prefix + "[" + i + "].Value"] = $("#" + listattrs[i].id.replace("Id", "Value")).val();
    }
}

// In create event of kendo grid
.Create(update => update.Action("createactionmethod","controller").Data("serialize");
```

Hope it helps someone in need.

Thank you!

Comment: The html is fine (and I assume that is inside form tags). Show you POST method.

Comment: I figured it was Kendo grid that was not intervening. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you have a scenario where you have to populate existing values in list to UI and if that list may grow by user interaction then the easiest way to bind dynamic lists to the controller is by mapping and creating a JS array and then stringify this and bind to hidden control in form and then submit the form which binds this stringified JS array to the string parameter of corresponding action method, then deserialize that string to the valid format in that action method.
mapping and creating JS array can be done by giving common class names to the HTML controls and getElementsByClassName.

if from DB you want to display the data in UI, get data from db and populate that data in the ChildModels property.

```
public class MyModel
{
   public MyModel()
   {
       ChildModels = new List<ChildModels>();
   }
   // other properties
   public List<ChildModel> ChildModels {get; set;}

   // if you want to use the same model to submit, bind to this property
   //public string StringifiedJSArray {get; set;}
}

public class ChildModel
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int Name {get;set;}
   public int Value {get;set;}
}

in cshtml :

@model MyModel;
<button onclick="addChild()">Add Child</button>
<form id="myForm" asp-action="submit" asp-controller="..."> 
  <div id="myDiv">
    //only if you need to populate data in UI from backend
    @foreach(var child in Model.ChildModels)
    {        
      <input class="ChildName" value="child.Name">
      <input class="ChildValue" value="child.Value">        
    }
 <div>
 <input hidden name="StringifiedJSArray">
 <button type="button" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  function addChild(){
    $("myDiv").append('
      <input class="ChildName">
      <input class="ChildValue">
    ');
  }



function submit(){
   var Names = document.getElementsByClass('ChildName');
   var Values = document.getElementsByClass('ChildValue');
   var myArray = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < Names.length; i++)
   {
      var obj = {id:"Your custom logic",Name:Names[i].value,Values[i].value}
      myArray.push(obj);
   }
   document.getElementById('StringifiedJSArray').value = JSON.stringify(myArray);
   document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
  }
</script>
```

in controller action :

```
public void submit(string StringifiedJSArray)
{
    public List<ChildModel> Children = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChildModel>>(StringifiedJSArray)
    ...
    ... your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your MyModel constructor you have `List<ChildModels>`, and your prop type is `List<ChildModel>`. This might be the issue.